# Forma pythónica de encontrar valores máximos en un lista anidada según grupos de valores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una lista anidada con resultados, en este caso los resultados se obtienen del cálculo estructural de un edificio. En las listas el índice 0 hace referencia al nombre de las barras (vigas y pilares) de la estructura.

```
resultados =[[1, 95, 'a0'], [2, 11, 'b0'], [3, 42, 'c0'], [4, 45, 'd0'],
             [1, 42, 'a1'], [2, 72, 'b1'], [3, 12, 'c1'], [4, 85, 'd1'],
             [1, 14, 'a2'], [2, 64, 'b2'], [3, 57, 'c2'], [4, 96, 'd2']]
```

Por otro lado, tengo una lista con las barras de las cuales quiero encontrar el correspondiente valor máximo en la lista de resultados, en este caso en el índice 1.

```
barras = [1, 3]
```

(Para las barras 1 y 3 los valores máximos correspondientes serían 95 y 57.)

Una vez encontrado el valor máximo para cada barra de la lista quiero obtener una nueva lista que contenga únicamente para cada una de las barras la lista con el valor máximo.

He solucionado el problema creando primeramente una lista anidada con los resultados de cada una de las barras, aislando la lista con el valor máximo y añadiendo esta lista a una nueva lista con los resultados.

```
resultados_temp = []
resultados_max = []

for barra in barras:

    # Crea una lista anidada únicamente con las listas respectivas de la barra.
    for resultado in resultados:

        if resultado[0] == barra:

            resultados_temp.append(resultado)       

    resultado = []
    valor_max = []

    # Encuentra dentro de la lista anidada la lista con el valor máximo.
    for resultado_temp in resultados_temp:

        valor_max.append(resultado_temp[1])     # Indexa el valor.
        max_value = max(valor_max)              # Encuentra el valor máximo.
        max_index = valor_max.index(max_value)  # Encuentra el índice del valor máximo.

    # Guarda la lista con el valor máximo.
    resultado.append(resultados_temp[max_index]) 

    # Indexa la lista con el valor máximo en la lista con el resultado final.
    resultados_max.append(resultado[0])

    # Borra los resultados temporales.
    resultados_temp.clear()   

print('resultados máximos:', resultados_max)
```

Salida:

```
resultados máximos: [[1, 95, 'a0'], [3, 57, 'c2']]
```

Aunque esto funciona para mi objetivo, puede que se pueda escribir de una forma más directa y pythónica.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo de más 'pythónica' es en muchos casos relativo. No obstante, lo que es cierto es que puedes reducir y simplificar el código mucho, pero que mucho, usando [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) junto a una función lambda para filtrar los elementos según el tipo de barra:

```
resultados =[[1, 95, 'a0'], [2, 11, 'b0'], [3, 42, 'c0'], [4, 45, 'd0'],
             [1, 42, 'a1'], [2, 72, 'b1'], [3, 12, 'c1'], [4, 85, 'd1'],
             [1, 14, 'a2'], [2, 64, 'b2'], [3, 57, 'c2'], [4, 96, 'd2']]

barras = [1, 3]

res = [max(filter(lambda x:x[0] == barra, resultados)) for barra in barras]
print(res)
```

**Salida:**

> [[1, 95, 'a0'], [3, 57, 'c2']]

Simplemente por cada valor de `barras` filtramos `resultados` para que nos retorne un iterable que solo contiene ese valor en la primera columna. Al aplicar `max` sobre un conjunto de listas en las que el primer valor es igual obtenemos la lista con el segundo elemento mayor.

No solo se reduce el código de 15 a 1 línea sino que es mucho más eficiente, en mi caso aplicando ambos códigos 1000 veces usando la misma lista `barras` pero sobre una lista `resultados` de 10000 elementos obtengo estos tiempos de ejecución:

> ```
> Tu código :     208.47257709503174 segundos    
> filter + lambda:  0.01851296424865 segundos
> ```

Gran parte de ese tiempo se debe al uso de listas auxiliares en vez de iteradores y al método `append()`.

Si vas a trabajar con matrices de este tipo y si usas gran cantidad de datos te aconsejo usar librerías mucho más apropiadas para el manejo de datos como Pandas que trabaja junto a NumPy y permite mucha más eficiencia en este tipo de operaciones con conjuntos grandes de datos además de simplificar mucho el código.

Comment: ¡Sí que se simplifica el código!